# Lua - specifying library for coroutine

Tags: lua, require, coroutine, meta-method

Within my Lua scripts, I have multiple libraries using the same 'structure'. For example, I have a.lua what contains `require('b')` and `require('c')`. Both b.lua and c.lua have got an info function. b.lua let it print "b" and c.lua let it print "c". In a.lua I want to start a coroutine with either the info() from B.lua or C.lua.

This is my b.lua:

```
b = {}
function b.info()
  coroutine.yield()
  print("b")
  print("b2")
end
```

C.lua has a similiar structure, but most B's are replaced with C. When trying to start the coroutine with `local co = coroutine.create(b.info())` (what also is strange because usually it starts suspended) I get an error like "attempt to yield across metamethod/C-call boundary".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`coroutine.create(b.info())` calls `b.info` *before* resuming `co`.

You need to pass a function, not a function *call*, as in

```
local co = coroutine.create(b.info)
coroutine.resume(co)        -- prints nothing
coroutine.resume(co)        -- prints b, b2
```

or

```
co = coroutine.wrap(b.info)
co()
co()
```

Comment: I know that, but that has nothing to do with the error I get. I meant it was strange it started automatic. My problem was I got an error trying to yield my coroutine.